# Specify maven profile to use by aether

Tags: java, maven, karaf, aether, pax

I have packed karaf container in docker image, that should be used in test and production. There are different nexus repositories used (the artifacts for production repository are first deployed after successfull test) and I want to control, which repository to use through environment variables, because it's the most flexible solution (and also recommended way of configuring images in OpenShift etc.).

Is it possible to set maven profile that will be used by aether?

There is setting `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.settings` so I could deploy 2 setting.xml files and choose the correct one, but then the test could go through with even incorrect productive maven settings. Profiles seem to be more error-resistant way.

Answer (score 0):

- Use Karaf-maven-plugin to build your Karaf distribution.
- Define two profiles in the pom.xml of your Karaf distribution.
- set the appropriate profile when building your Karaf :

> mvn clean install **-P**prodProfile
>
> mvn clean install **-P**testProfile

- Start the already builded Karaf assembly: it must point to the good repository.

Comment: Sorry, you've misunderstood me. I'm not building karaf on each start, I have already pre-build karaf that need to download features.